# C++ copying memory from one type to another

Tags: c++

I'd like to save the bit values of a char[4] into an int.
Say "aaaa" is the string, I'd like the int to be 1633771873.

'a' is stored as 01100001 on one byte in memory, so "aaaa" is 
01100001 01100001 01100001 01100001, or 32  bits, which should fit into an int, and its decimal value is 1633771873.

How do I copy the bit value of my char[4] into the memory of the int ?

Comment: why do need it in the first place?

Comment: If it was "abcd", depending on endianess, you could get a variety of results.

Comment: school project :)
thing is we get a binary entry to our program and we have to parse it. Since we read the files with read() we get char*, and don't know how to copy what we read memory-wise to other types.

Comment: @cup true, didn't think of that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`std::memcpy(void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) like

```
std::memcpy(&my_int, my_char, 4);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the best solution for this specific case:

```
union U
{
    char c[4];
    int i;
};
```

Use it:

```
char arr[4] = "aaaa";

U u;
u.c[0] = arr[0];
u.c[1] = arr[1];
u.c[2] = arr[2];
u.c[3] = arr[3];

std::cout<< u.i; //use it
```

Unions also solve problem with endiannes (because layout of bytes in union will be platform-specific).

Comment: This is commonly called type-punning and is not valid in C++, although many compilers support it as a non-standard extension.

Comment: What does `htonl` have to do with the question?

Comment: I would say every compiler, that means something on the market. But yes, it is technically non-standard. However, paradoxically, this solution may be probably the most portable one.

Comment: @Barry Yeah, sure, thanks.

Comment: *"Unions also solve problem with endiannes"* - that's not true, in the sense that `c[0]` will give you either the most significant byte (little-endian) or the least significant (big-endian). So you still have to pay attention to endianness. In fact, most people use such a union to decide the endianness of a system.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by shifting each element of the char array and summing them up:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* a = "aaaa";
    unsigned int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< 4; ++i)
    {
        result += ((unsigned int)a[i]) << (32-i*8); 
    }
    std::cout<< result;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously memcpy would be good for this, but I don't think it is really good idea to write that kind of code. It depends on your CPU architecture, becouse your integer will be different on Little Endian and Big Endian CPUs.
Obviously not in this case, where all bytes are the same, but in general.

Answer (score 0):

What about this,

```
const char *pcString = "aaaa";
int *ptrToInt = new int();

memcpy(ptrToInt, pcString, 4);
```